# Limit of $\exp\cdot \sinh x$

Tags: calculus, limits

Please, help me to prove that 
$$
\lim_{\theta \to \infty} \sinh\theta \cdot \exp(-a\cdot \cosh\theta)=0
$$
for $a>0$. I have already tried L'Hopital rule, wrote $\cosh$ by definition, but nothing helped.

Thanks in advance

Comment: L'Hopital worked fine for me. Can you show what you tried so that I (and others) can see what you did?

Comment: Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use equivalents : when $\theta$ is large $\sinh(\theta)\sim \cosh(\theta)\sim \frac 12 e^\theta$ which make
$$y=\sinh(\theta) \, \exp(-a\cdot \cosh(\theta) \sim \frac 12 \, e^\theta \exp(-\frac a 2e^\theta)$$ Let $t=\frac 12 e^\theta$ to make
$$y \sim t e^{-a t}$$ which is easy.

Answer (score 0):

If $a<0$, then

$$\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\sinh\left(\theta\right)e^{-a\cosh(\theta)}=\infty\cdot e^\infty=\infty$$
on the other hand, if  $a=0$, then, again
$$\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\sinh\left(\theta\right)=\infty$$
however, if $a>0$, use the definition of $\sinh(\cdot)$
$$\sinh\left(\theta\right)e^{-a\cosh(\theta)}=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{\theta }-e^{-\theta }\right) e^{-a \cosh (\theta )}=\frac12\left(e^{-a \cosh (\theta )+\theta}-e^{-\left[ a\cosh (\theta )+\theta\right]}\right)$$
but
$$\lim_{\theta\to\infty}e^{-\left[a \cosh (\theta )+\theta\right]}=\exp\left[-\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\left(a\cosh (\theta )+\theta\right)\right]=e^{-\infty}=0$$
so
$$\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\sinh\left(\theta\right)e^{-a\cosh(\theta)}=\frac12\lim_{\theta\to\infty}e^{-a \cosh (\theta )+\theta}$$
for the second limit, consider the following limit
$$\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\frac{\cosh(\theta)}{\theta}\to\text{L'H.}\to\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\sinh(\theta)=\infty$$
so
$$\frac12\lim_{\theta\to\infty}e^{-a \cosh (\theta )+\theta}=\frac12\exp\left(\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\theta\left[-a\frac{\cosh(\theta)}{\theta}+1\right)\right]=\frac12\exp(-\infty\cdot\infty)=0.$$
In other words,
$$\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\sinh\left(\theta\right)e^{-a\cosh(\theta)}=\begin{cases}
\infty,\,\,&\text{if $a\leq0$}\\
0, &\text{if $a>0$}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\cosh u=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 u}$$hence by defining $u=\sinh u$, for $\theta>0$ we obtain $$0<\sinh\theta \cdot \exp(-a\cdot \cosh\theta){=u\exp{(-a\sqrt{1+u^2})}\\\le u\exp{(-a\sqrt{u^2})}\\=u\exp(-a|u|)\\=u\exp(-au)}$$which very simply tends to $0$, and the proof is complete by squeeze theorem.